# Can you change the type of Active Directory Password Complexity to be different than MS version?

Tags: active-directory

Here it states that the policy must adhere to

- Passwords must meet complexity requirements determines whether password complexity is enforced. If this setting is enabled, user passwords meet the following requirements:
- The password is at least six characters long.
- The password contains characters from at least three of the following five categories:

  - English uppercase characters (A - Z)
  - English lowercase characters (a - z)
  - Base 10 digits (0 - 9)
  - Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
  - Unicode characters
- The password does not contain three or more characters from the user's account name.

They only setting is to ENABLE or DISABLE this feature.

I was wondering if there is a way to change this policy?  IF so where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so using a Password Filter, but its a pretty complex to do so. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721884(VS.85).aspx) on how to do so.

There are a number of third party password filters availible to do this such as:

- [NFront](http://nfrontsecurity.com/products/nfront-password-filter/)
- [SpecOps](http://www.specopssoft.com/products/specops-password-policy)

Comment: +1 for the 3rd-party options, didn't even realise they existed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by writing your own custom password filter DLL, which needs to be installed on each DC in your domain/s. MSDN and/or TechNet will have the details, but it's not simple from what I understand.